# How to fix: 'undefined is not an object'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Trying to run the iOS simulator for an app made with React Native via Atom text editor. I previously had an error message saying "react native module does not exist in module map ". I tried to fix it by updating react native, re-ran the iOS simulator via command line with 'react-native run-ios' and got this. How can I fix this through command line?

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arjn9.png)

Comment: show us your code, we don't know what happen without your code.

Comment: Have you tried to use the newest version of React Native?